# How to test repeated, nested, count data

Tags: repeated-measures, modeling, multilevel-analysis, count-data, nested-data

I have samples from an experiment in which I have counted cells. I took 2 pictures of each kidney, photographing both kidneys of each subject. Each individual belongs to a group (infection). My hypothesis is that I will have different numbers of cells per group. My problem in that I can't do one-way ANOVA, because the values I have are not independent. Using the average per individual would not be correct. Then I thought about fitting a nested model, but in the end, the picture/kidney are not really important (I don't want to know if choosing one or the other will have any effects)... I just took the different pictures and chose both kidneys to low the error that I could be adding (for example by choosing a specific kidney or area of the kidney)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that pops into my mind is doing a mixed model approach to take into account the fact that you have correlated (but grouped) observations. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/glmm.htm)